# Adding nested structure to flat json

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and json, I have a flat json that I get as response after querying a table and the structure is as follows

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "First Name": "Jack",
    "Last Name": "Jill",
    "Mobile phone": "1234567",
    "Home Phone": "0123456",
    "Address Line1": "xxxx",
    "Address Line2": "xxxx",
    "City": "New York"
}
```

I want to convert this flat json into a nested one using some javascript function and I want to convert it as follows. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

```
{
    "Person": {
        "id": "123",
        "First Name": "Jack",
        "Last Name": "Jill",
        "phone": {
            "Home Phone": "0123456",
            "Mobile Phone": "1234567"
        },
        "Address": {
            "Address Line1": "xxxx",
            "Address Line2": "xxxx",
            "City": "New York"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you could use an object for the path of the items to be nested.

> ```
> {
>     "Mobile phone": "phone",
>     "Home Phone": "phone",
>     "Address Line1": "Address",
>     "Address Line2": "Address",
>     "City": "Address"
> }
> ```

Then check if the key is in the object and use the value to build a new object if necessary. Later assign the value of the original object.

```js
var object = { "id": "123", "First Name": "Jack", "Last Name": "Jill", "Mobile phone": "1234567", "Home Phone": "0123456", "Address Line1": "xxxx", "Address Line2": "xxxx", "City": "New York" },
    groups = { "Mobile phone": "phone", "Home Phone": "phone", "Address Line1": "Address", "Address Line2": "Address", "City": "Address" },
    result = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if (k in groups) {
        result[groups[k]] = result[groups[k]] || {};
        result[groups[k]][k] = object[k];
        return;
    }
    result[k] = object[k];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. What you probably want to do is something around this path:

```
var flatJSONObject = {"id":"123","First Name": "Jack", "Last Name":"Jill", 
"Mobile phone":"1234567", "Home Phone":"0123456","Address Line1":"xxxx",
 "Address Line2":"xxxx", "City":"New York"};

var newJSONObject = {
    person: {
    id: flatJSONObject.id,
    firstName: flatJSONObject['First Name'],
    lastName: flatJSONObject['Last Name'],
    phone:{
        homePhone: flatJSONObject['Home Phone'],
      mobilePhone: flatJSONObject['Mobile phone']
    },
    address: {
        addressLine1: flatJSONObject['Address Line1'],
        addressLine2: flatJSONObject['Address Line2'],
      city: flatJSONObject.City
    }
  }
} 

console.log(newJSONObject);
```